# How to get image size in forms.py

Tags: django, django-forms

I am extending forms clean method to get the image size but I need to get the size of the image while extending the ModelForm.

In the form below I am able to get the image size in bytes in the clean method but I am not sure how to get that in **init**.

One important point, this should get the image size before it is saved on the database.

This thing is turning me head in for more than a week now :(. can someone help with this please.

**forms.py**

```
class PhotoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean_old_image(self):
        image = self.cleaned_data.get('old_image', False)
        print 'old_image._size', image.size
        return image


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(PhotoForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        image_size = **# SHOULD BE ABLE TO GET THE IMAGE SIZE HERE**
        self.fields['old_image'] = ProcessedImageField(spec_id='myapp:test_app:old_image',
                                           processors=[CustomCompress()],
                                           format='JPEG',
                                           options={'quality': 60}
                                           )
    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = ['old_image']
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but when you instantiate your PhotoForm with a Photo model as in:

```
photo = Photo.objects.get(id=1)
photo_form = PhotoForm(instance=photo)
```

then image_size could simply be retrieved via

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(PhotoForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.instance:
        image_size = self.instance.image.size
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am looking for real time upload image size not sure if this is going to give the desired results.

Comment: This would be prior to instantiating the object

Comment: If you're looking for real time, do you mean that when the user uploads an image in the form (without submitting it yet), then its size should be indicated to the user? You'll need to use Javascript calls for that, that's outside of Django's realm.